# Increase code coverage in SonarQube after successfully performing a unit test

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, sonarqube, junit5

Good afternoon, i need help with one thing please.
I realised a unit unitary test in eclipse to a java code, and to test a part of the code in particular and increase the coverage of the code in SonarQube, i copied a public method of a class from the java file, i executed it and it was well, but doesnt  increase the coverage of the code.
And the unit test is fine.
Why does this happen?
I realised the test with JUnit5.

I need the coverage in 80% in overview, but although i do the unitary test, the coverage doesnt change.`enter code here`
Thank you very much for your help
Best regards.

Comment: SonarQube relies on the converage results provided (made by another tool). Also know you can create many unit-tests without increasing the converage.

Comment: How much percent is the branch coverage of your project?

Comment: I must have at least 80%